# Check if string.at(i) is a whitespace C++

Tags: c++, string, char, whitespace

I want to check if a `char` (`string.at(i)`) is whitespace in C++. How can I do this easily?

I got this code example, and I was thinking to change the `_____` with something, but don't know what. I've tried with `' '`, but that didn't work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)
{
    if(string.at(i) == _________)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: `string[i] == ' '` should work, if you want very simple check.

Comment: There's no reason to use `at` here, because you know the index is valid.

Comment: @muntoo: blank is not the only white space character.

Comment: Right.  There's also `\t`, `\r`, and `\n`, and perhaps a few other control characters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#include <cctype>

if (isspace(string.at(i)))
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `==` [something], you want: `if (isspace(string.at(i))` (or you might prefer to use `std::isspace`).

Edit: I should add that depending on what you're *doing* with the space characters (or what you're going with everything else, depending) you might want to use an algorithm. Just for example, if you wanted to create a copy of your string with all the whitespace characters removed, you could use:

```
std::remove_copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(new_string), isspace);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unrepentant C programmers migrating to C++ would semi-automatically use:

```
#include <cctype>

if (std::isspace(string.at(i)))
    ...
```

It is quite likely to be the correct even for C++ programmers.